# how to use CASE WHEN in access syntax error

Tags: ms-access

First post here so go easy, I am new to access and queries,

I have the below which I want to create a case to change a 1 or 0 into an on or off in a merged document,

Below is what I have tried but it shows a syntax error? Is there another better way? I have had a search but cant see a solution,

```
NZ((SELECT TOP 1 left(CASE chrConfigValue WHEN 'TRUE' THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END, 255) FROM dbo_*Table*_parts_config WHERE idpart= dbo_*Table*_parts.idconfig AND left(chrConfigName, 255) = 'DHCP_SERVER_STATE'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access doesn't support `CASE`, use `IIF` instead:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    LEFT(IIF(chrConfigValue = 'TRUE', 'ON, 'OFF'), 255)
FROM dbo_Table_parts_config
WHERE
    idpart = dbo_Table_parts.idconfig AND
    LEFT(chrConfigName, 255) = 'DHCP_SERVER_STATE'
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm afraid that I can only help you with the raw SQL part of your question.  Access usage issues are beyond my pay grade.

Comment: Hi Tim, Sorted it, i used SWITCH and worked straight away thank you for your help,